# How do I use Google Autho 2.0 response token properly for easy login access?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, token

The problem is that the response token from Google Auth 2.0 is decodable without a secret key.

The decoded token contains the following keys:

iss

azp

aud

sub

email

email_verified

nbf

name

picture

given_name

locale

iat

exp

jti.

My concern is that someone can simply tokenize a similar object and place anyone's email. Then, when that token is sent to my api, it would just search by email.

I am not sure which variable, above, could be used to verify if the token is authentic.

I tried reading through the docs, but it was general information.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/token-types

Comment: Yes you can read a JWT easily. But you can't temper it, if you apply the correct verification. Indeed, the token is signed; You have to check the signature and if the signer is a trusted entity. Like that, if the token is updated and signed, without changing the signature, the check will fail. If it is updated and signed again (self signed or other), the signature will be valid but the authority won't be approved. So, no worries, the internet works well with OAuth2, there is no issue!